# Speeding up loop when normalizing Pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
|  col1  | heading |
|--------|---------|
|heading1|   true  |
|abc     |  false  |
|efg     |  false  |
|hij     |  false  |
|heading2|   true  |
|klm     |  false  |
|...     |  false  |
```

This data is actually "sequential" and I would like to transform it to this structure:

```
|  col1  |  Parent   |
|---------------------
|heading1|  heading1 |
|abc     |  heading1 | 
|efg     |  heading1 |
|hij     |  heading1 |
|heading2|  heading2 |
|klm     |  heading2 |
|...     |  headingN |
```

I have +10M rows so this method takes too long:

```
df['Parent'] = df['col1']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['heading']:
        current = row['col1']
    else:
        row.loc[index, 'Parent'] = current
```

Do you have any advice on a faster process?

Comment: How about using a fill function?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `mask` with `ffill`:

```
df.assign(heading=df.col1.mask(~df.col1.str.startswith('heading')).ffill())
```

```
       col1   heading
0  heading1  heading1
1       abc  heading1
2       efg  heading1
3       hij  heading1
4  heading2  heading2
5       klm  heading2
```

---

This works by replacing any value that does not start with `heading` with `NaN`, and then fills the last non-nan value forward:

```
df.col1.mask(~df.col1.str.startswith('heading'))
```

```
0    heading1
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4    heading2
5         NaN
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

```
df.col1.mask(~df.col1.str.startswith('heading')).ffill()
```

```
0    heading1
1    heading1
2    heading1
3    heading1
4    heading2
5    heading2
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, also had a ffill in mind. But this doesn't even use the column heading. Smart

Answer (score 3):

Probably not a very pandas-idiomatic solution but you can `cumsum` the logical column and use that to grab the corresponding heading for each row. In essence we're defining a piecewise-constant index array that only gets incremented for each `True` value on the original `heading` column.

```
import pandas as pd

# set up some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'heading': [True, False, False, False, True, False, False]},
                  index=['heading1', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'heading2', 'quux', 'quuz'])

# get every 'heading' index
headings = df.index[df.heading]
# fetch which row corresponds to which 'heading'
indices = df.heading.cumsum() - 1
# fetch the actual headings for each row
df['parent'] = headings[indices]

print(df)
```

The output of the above code is

```
          heading    parent
heading1     True  heading1
foo         False  heading1
bar         False  heading1
baz         False  heading1
heading2     True  heading2
quux        False  heading2
quuz        False  heading2
```

From which you can `drop` the unnecessary `heading` column. Of course you can directly get the logical array you have and work with that:

```
headline = df.index.str.startswith('heading') # bool Series
headings = df.index[headline]
indices = df.heading.cumsum() - 1
df['parent'] = headings[indices]
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought of a ffill too. By using df.pop() we make sure the column disappears too.

```
df['Parent'] = df['col1'].mul(df.pop('heading')).replace('',np.nan).ffill()
```

---

**Full example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['heading1', 'abc', 'efg', 'hij', 'heading2', 'klm'],
    'heading': [True, False, False, False, True, False]
})

df['Parent'] = df['col1'].mul(df.pop('heading')).replace('',np.nan).ffill()
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
       col1    Parent
0  heading1  heading1
1       abc  heading1
2       efg  heading1
3       hij  heading1
4  heading2  heading2
5       klm  heading2
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `where` + `pop` + `ffill`

You may find this more efficient. Data from @AntonvBR.

```
df['Parent'] = df['col1'].where(df.pop('heading')).ffill()

print(df)

       col1    Parent
0  heading1  heading1
1       abc  heading1
2       efg  heading1
3       hij  heading1
4  heading2  heading2
5       klm  heading2
```

Comment: Ohhh you... I was looking for this. I knew it ... (was laboring with np.where).

Answer (score 1):

To throw in a completely different method, you could obtain an index by iterating through your boolean array and afterwards using it as a map for your headers. I don't know how fast the header mapping is but you can index the booleans quickly..

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
bool_array = np.array([True, False], dtype=np.bool)
boolean_array = np.random.choice(bool_array, size=100000000)
@jit(nopython=True)
def reassign(boolean_array):
    b = np.zeros(shape=(len(boolean_array),), dtype=np.int32)
    b[0] = 0
    for i in range(1,len(boolean_array)):
        if boolean_array[i]:
            b[i] = i
        else:
            b[i] = b[i-1]
    return b

import time
start = time.time()
print(reassign(boolean_array))
print("took {} seconds".format(time.time()-start))
```

> Takes 0.5 seconds with Numba and 130 seconds without, for 100mm